# How to change unit_test/fix pure function errors

Tags: c++

```
/usr/include/boost/test/auto_unit_test.hpp:17:1: note: #pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use This header is deprecated. Please use <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> instead. instead.
17 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED( "This header is deprecated. Please use <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> instead." )
  | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       [C++] jml/arch/simd_vector.cc
./jml/arch/simd_vector.cc:46:61: error: ‘pure’ attribute on function returning ‘void’ [-Werror=attributes]
   46 | void vec_scale(const float * x, float k, float * r, size_t n)
  |                                                             ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

make: *** [jml/arch//arch.mk:27: build/x86_64/obj/jml/arch/simd_vector.894c3fd093070a25659bff4e67647992.lo] Error

Also: /jml/arch/fslock.cc:23:18: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a          template type
23 |     typedef std::function<void ()> Fn;
|                  ^~~~~~~~
./jml/arch/fslock.cc:14:1: note: ‘std::function’ is defined in header ‘’; did you forget to ‘#include ’?
13 | #include "fslock.h"
+++ |+#include 
14 |
./jml/arch/fslock.cc:25:22: error: ‘Fn’ does not name a type
25 |     Call_Guard(const Fn & fn)
|                      ^~
./jml/arch/fslock.cc:36:5: error: ‘Fn’ does not name a type
36 |     Fn fn_;
|     ^~
./jml/arch/fslock.cc: In constructor ‘{anonymous}::Call_Guard::Call_Guard(const          int&)’:
./jml/arch/fslock.cc:26:11: error: class ‘{anonymous}::Call_Guard’ does not have
any field named ‘fn_’
26 |         : fn_(fn)
|           ^~~
./jml/arch/fslock.cc: In destructor ‘{anonymous}::Call_Guard::~Call_Guard()’:
./jml/arch/fslock.cc:32:13: error: ‘fn_’ was not declared in this scope
32 |         if (fn_) fn_();
|

Comment: `error: ‘pure’ attribute on function returning ‘void’`. Pure means that there are no side-effects. If you don't have any side-effects and don't return anything, then nothing will happen.

Comment: It won't pass compile, how to eliminate the error when make?  @TedKleinBergman

Comment: I don't know, there's too little information. I don't know why this is a problem with boost, but the problem is what I specified above. However, that's just a warning but there seems to be an option turned on that makes warning to errors. You could try to disable that. It should be in one of the Makefiles.

Comment: I took it out, now error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type and no matching function for call to ‘{anonymous}  @TedKleinBergman

Comment: You should probably edit in more details into your question. I recognized the error, but I don't know how the library you're using is supposed to be compiled. If you edit more information, it'll be easier for someone with more knowledge about boost to answer. To me it sounds like you might be using a too old version of the library (as it says _"Please use <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> instead"),_ but I don't know.